# Differentiate between nested update, insert and delete with MongoDB change streams

Tags: mongodb

When dealing with a nested array in a Mongo document, whether inserting, deleting or updating, you will use `db.collection.update()`

The problem I am running into is with the new Change Streams in v3.6+.

I need a way to differentiate between these operations in the change events that come from `collection.watch()`

**Examples:**

using document schema:

```
{
  id: string,
  array: [{id: string, value: string}]
}
```

**insert** to nested array:

```
collection.updateOne(
    {id: 'some_id'},
    {$push: {'array.$': {id: 'nested_id', value: 'new nested item'} } }
)
```

the change stream will respond with:

```
{
  ...
  operationType: 'update',
  updateDescription: {
    updatedFields: 'array.0': {id: 'nested_id', value: 'new nested item'}
  ... }
}
```

**update** nested array item:

```
collection.updateOne(
    {id: 'some_id', 'array.id': 'nested_id'},
    {$set: {'array.$.name': 'new nested name' } }
)
```

the change stream will respond with:

```
{
  ...
  operationType: 'update',
  updateDescription: {
    updatedFields: 'array.0.name': 'new nested name'
  ... }
}
```

**delete** nested array item:

```
collection.updateOne(
    {id: 'some_id'},
    {$pull: {array: {id: 'nested_id'} } }
)
```

the change stream will respond with:

```
{
  ...
  operationType: 'update',
  updateDescription: {
    updatedFields: 'array': [...all items in array besides the one you just pulled]
  ... }
}
```

I can see a couple of janky ways to differentiate between these events, such as `'array.0.name'.split('.')`, and if the last element is a number then it was a nested insert, otherwise it's an update or delete. That works, though I don't really like it.

But it doesn't seem like there is any good way to tell the different between a nested delete and insert. Any help on this issue would be great.

Comment: Did you find any better solution, than `.split('.')`

Comment: unfortunately no. i will update if i do though!

Comment: I also have the same use case. Even if we could find a way to differentiate all three operations, we would still not know (in case of delete) which array elements were deleted.

Comment: And since Mongo 3.6+ field names can have dots in their names. This means that 'foo.0' might even be an object **or** an indicator for an array. IMHO this implementation is flawed, the only solution I can think of is to check the `fullDocument`, but race conditions might occur.

Answer (score 0):

The change stream response examples you showed for each operation contain only one instance in which the updated field points to an array, that being the delete/pull scenario. Therefore, check if `updatedFields.array` exists and is an array.

```js
if(Array.isArray(response.updateDescription.updatedFields["array"]) {
 // it's a $pull operation; do stuff
}
```